# Time complexity of this algorithm with constant loop

Tags: algorithm

I know that:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 1337; i++){
   printf("\n");
  }
```

Is **O(1)** since we have **1337** irrespective of `n`

But what about:

```
char * s = "abcdef";
for(int i = 0; i < 1337; i++){
       strlen(s);
      }
```

Is this **O(N)** now? Please any one explain

Comment: Is there any N in the second example?

Comment: and from what aspect the TC should be any different for above two cases?

Comment: It is O(1337 * |s|) which is O(|s|) now, if you meant s is variable.
But what exactly is your question, I still do not get it...

Answer (score 0):

If you have a constant input the complexity of the algorithm will always be O(1) as you will perform the same number of operations.

If, however, `s` is input to your algorithm, the complexity will become `O(len(s))`. Note that `O(N)` has no meaning in this example as you have no not defined what is `N`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define what `N` is. Your first example is O(1) no matter how you view it. Your second example is O(N) in the length of `s` because `strlen` is O(N).

Comment: Who came up with the idea to define everything? In big-O notation, literally anything can serve as a descriptor. If I write `O(M^N)` it's perfectly clear that complexity is bound by some variable parts denoted as `M` and `N` with insane complexity of `M^N` - only when I want to get into details like expected value ranges it becomes helpful to know the origin of `M` and `N`. It's not required for an abstract complexity statement

Comment: @grek40 - Not sure what you mean - if you don't specify what input/variable/etc. N relates to then O(N) is pretty meaningless.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth on some level there needs to be a definition. However, I'd argue in the context of big-O, any displayed `M,N,...` (unless defined otherwise) can be interpreted as representing some linear scaling input which contributes to complexity in the denoted way. Not everyone is interested in the detailed mapping of representation. Now when I have a linear complexity constraint, I can use any `O(N)` function a limited number of times even without knowing what `N` is in detail.

Comment: @grek40, the reason we are all putting focus on the issue "define N" is that gar seems to think that N always have to be the loop. I have worked two years as a teaching assistant in an introductory algorithm course and have seen this beginner mistake dozens of times. Sure, we who already understand asymptotic algorithm analysis doesn't need the N to be explicitly defined all the time, but beginners often need to be explicit until they learn.